# Did any of the Doctor's assistants ever need psychological counselling?

Tags: doctor-who

Given the number of times the Doctor's assistants have the sorts of experiences that would send most people off for counselling, did any of them actually need or have this? As far as I know (thankfully never having had one), near-death experiences are pretty unsettling!

To clarify, I'm talking within the programme, not whether any of the actors or actresses needed counselling after filming.

Comment: Even in the whoniverse people are still skeptical about aliens and all that stuff. If you tell your shrink you nearly died because of a tin robot that can be defeated by stair, chances are they'll send you to an institution. I'm not the downvoter, BTW...

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2019-05-26/doctor-who-david-tennant-fame/amp/

Comment: Donna had all her experiences of the Doctor wiped or blocked by the Doctor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Young Amy Pond required counselling in *[The Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_(Doctor_Who))* as a result of her retaining memories of celestial objects such as stars.

Her psychologist is a lady named [Christine](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Christine_(The_Big_Bang)). Her qualifications aren't discussed in any detail but she appears to be a child therapist or psychiatrist.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, although according to that page, she seems to have needed counselling for other reasons, not due to a near-death experience!

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel - Technically it was the experience of **the entire universe dying** that led to her needing counselling, so I could that as a win since she was inside the universe at the time.

Comment: Fair point, sounds like a fairly traumatic experience!